# Invoking of an event when an entry is expired in ehcache

Tags: java, ehcache

I want to implement a caching mechanism in which each entry in the cache has its own expiry time, also when a particular entry gets expired I need to invoke an event which will delete this entry from the Database as well.So far I have tried EhCache with which I am not able to meet all my requirements (as mentioned above). I am able to create a cache which has a fixed time of expiry for every entry but I am not able to invoke any method on the expiring event.So my questions are :

1) Is it possible to attach a "time to live" for every entry in an ehcahce? If yes,please mention how to achieve it.
2) Do I need to invoke the method "notifyElementExpired" of CacheEventListener manually or it is fired    as soon as an entry gets expired?
A sample code would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check [this doc](http://ehcache.org/documentation/apis/cache-event-listeners) ?

Comment: Yes I checked this link.I implemented CacheEventListener class,also registered my Factory class in ehcache.xml. But my method in the implementer class never gets called that is why I had mentioned second point in my question.

Answer (score 0):

There is no expiry thread, pro actively expiring things in the background, but you could easily add that yourself and use net.sf.ehcache.Cache#getKeysWithExpiryCheck.

Expiry in Ehcache only happens inline (or at least for unclustered use-case, if you cluster with Terracotta, that's not entirely true anymore).